# Extending scalars to Quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Let **M** be an **A**-module, and **a** be an ideal of **A**. Then we denote by **M/aM** the **A/a**-module obtained from the quotient of **M** by the submodule generated by *ax* for *a*∈**a** and *x*∈**M**.
> This  module can be thus defined through the extension of scalars to  **A/a** from the **A**-module **M**

So I just learnt what extension of scalars and tensor products of modules are, after seeing this in a textbook, and I was wondering if somebody could give me a few concrete examples of the above situation, so I can grasp what's going on. For example did they **have to** quotient by **aM** before extending scalars? I wouldn't have thought so, since every **A**-Module should be an **A/a**-module by extension of scalars using the natural quotient map.
So I imagine this is a special case? When it has a particularly straightforward structure? I'm very unfamiliar so I was hoping somebody could give me some pointers

EDIT: I see they were saying that these two are identical. But nevertheless, since I'm unfamiliar with scalar extension, if anybody has examples of extending scalars to modules over the quotient ring I would find it very helpful.

Comment: This is equivalent, since $M/\mathfrak a M\simeq M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak a$.

Comment: Oh I see what they were saying. I will try proving this. Do you have any good examples of extension to a quotient ring outside of this case?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you have in mind  with `extension to a quotient ring`.

Comment: I mean extending scalars using the quotient map from an A-module to an A/a-module. Even examples in this case would be helpful as I only learnt about this topic today

Comment: Forr instancen=, a standard method to prove the irreducibility of a polynomial in $\mathbf Z[X]$  consists in showing its reduction in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z[X]$ is irreducible.